# Ruby - error rendering a view referencing a loop that I never wrote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this controller:

```
class AlexesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /alexes
  # GET /alexes.json
  def index
    #@alexes = Alex.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @alexes }
    end
  end

  # GET /alexes/1
  # GET /alexes/1.json
  def show
  #  @alex = Alex.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @alex }
    end
  end

  # GET /alexes/new
  # GET /alexes/new.json
  def new
    @alex = Alex.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @alex }
    end
  end

  # GET /alexes/1/edit
  def edit
    @alex = Alex.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /alexes
  # POST /alexes.json
  def create
    @alex = Alex.new(params[:alex])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @alex.save
        format.html { redirect_to @alex, notice: 'Alex was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @alex, status: :created, location: @alex }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @alex.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /alexes/1
  # PUT /alexes/1.json
  def update
    @alex = Alex.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @alex.update_attributes(params[:alex])
        format.html { redirect_to @alex, notice: 'Alex was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @alex.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /alexes/1
  # DELETE /alexes/1.json
  def destroy
    @alex = Alex.find(params[:id])
    @alex.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to alexes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

It gets called when this link gets pressed:

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", alexes_path(@alex) %>
```

so I am assuming that the get-all part of the controller would get invoked, and I commented out lines in the controller that I thought would get invoked, but I still get this error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

from line 10:

```
7:     <th></th>
8:   </tr>
9: 
10: <% @alexes.each do |alex| %>
11:   <tr>
12:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', alex %></td>
13:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_alex_path(alex) %></td>
```

Any idea where the problem is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: @fl00r I thought commenting that line would stop the application from making a db call since I didn't make a schema yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", alexes_path(@alex) %>
```

=>

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", alex_path(@alex) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", @alex %>
```

Comment: thanks. I am still confused about the differences of each of those syntaxes. Whats the difference between them?  Thanks again!

Comment: It is convention. When you need something singular (one Alex) you should write singular routes, and if you want to get a bunch of items you should use pluralized routes

Comment: thanks! and the 3rd line..what implication does it have if you don't use the alex_path() ?

Comment: Also, how would it effect the error I am encountering? Where is that each loop? I dont see it in the controller.

Comment: It's in your view. `@alexes.each do |alex|`. :)

Comment: @ardavis thanks! I commented out that line in the view, but then it gave an error here "<td><%= link_to 'Show', alex %></td>" - why would that happen? I thought I already have code for that in my controller.

Comment: No need to comment out the lines. `@alexes = blah` in the controller is setting the instance variable. In the view, it is simply looping through your instance variable and displaying each one at a time.